# Pyspark filtering while reading json files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a json files containing a months worth of network comms and getting OOM errors. The read instruction contains filters that will greatly reduce the quantity of records.

```
    process_df = (spark.read.json(input_file)
                  .filter((F.col("initiated") == "true")
                           & ((F.col("dest_port") == "80")
                           | (F.col("dest_port") == "443"))))

    process_df.count()
```

I think that the way this gets implemented, in spite of lazy evaluation, is that the data is read into executors and then the filter is applied as a transform when count is called? Is this correct?

I did try to get around the memory issues by adding a

```
.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

but that resulted in a hung job with a ton of rpc errors.

I think my solution is to read my data in smaller chunks, filter and then combine. I'm really trying to get an understanding of whether my mental model of how Spark is operating is correct.

Comment: no; only the filtered data is being read here ... your cluster config is probably not utilizing enough resources ... what mode are you running this?  how much data are you working with?

Comment: The raw data is 624GB. The cluster is running in yarn mode. The job is running with this config. 
    ("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", 'false'),
    ("spark.driver.memory", "80G"),
    ("spark.executor.cores", "2"),
    ("spark.executor.memory", "55G"),
    ("spark.driver.maxResultSize","40G"),
    ("spark.yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled","false"),
    ("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1400mb"),
    ("spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem","1500mb"),
    ("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","500"),
    ])

Comment: will need to customize that to your cluster specs ... why is your driver RAM so big?

Comment: @kupe any reason for setting `spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage` to false The above code is a single stage job and the transformations above support codegen, which can reduce virtual function calls and to an extent memory consumption as well. Also, can we check if `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is enabled, and `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` is set to a high value, so that cluster resources gets utilized. Also, Is the data compressed ?

Comment: you can also try to repartition your data `(spark.read.json(input_file).repartition(...)`. To calculate the partitions number you can do `total / 500MB = 1248`. How many nodes does your cluster have?

Comment: @thePurplePython - good catch. I'm not really bringing anything back to driver at this point so lowered that and spark.driver.maxResultSize down to 10 GB. Job is allocating most of the memory available (512GB) on cluster but still hits a java OOM error and dies.

Comment: @DaRkMaN - I had been getting plan truncated errors later in the code when I was running it on less data and tried the codegen.wholeStage as a solution to that. I removed it. dynamicAllocation is enabled. maxExecutors is current unset.  The docs indicate that should let Yarn decide. The data is gzipped.

Comment: @Alexandros - I tried repartitioning it to 2k partitions but same error. Cluster has 7 nodes with 512GB allocated to Yarn total.

Comment: @kupe Since the compression format is Gzip, it i snt splittable compression format. The entire file has to processed by a single task. If the compression was splittibale(BZip2, LZO, and Snappy), we could tune `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`(defaulting to 128MB), which will spit the task into smaller chunks and hence avoid OOM.

Comment: @kupe you can try to increase the number of executors per node since it seems to have quite large nodes. Cores up to 5 per executor, memory up to 10-12GB per executor. Memory larger than 10GB may cause high latencies to GC hence it is suggested to keep executors memory within these limits